# Log the exceptions of jar execution in loop, through bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Input list values - a,b,c,d

This is my bash script for executing the jar file in loop:

```
cd /myjarfilepath

for input in $list
do

java -Xmx1024m -cp myApp.jar com.CommandLineRunner $input 
done
```

When I execute myApp.jar with input "a" - It fails with null pointer exception and continues to execute for next input "b". Here I want to log the null pointer exception for "a" before it proceed to "b".

I tried to get the exit status by using below code, but its always 0 even the process contains exceptions.

```
my_status=$?
echo The exit status of the process was $my_status
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect `stderr` to your log file:

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp myApp.jar com.CommandLineRunner $input 2>> all.log
```

Or you can create an individual log for each input file:

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp myApp.jar com.CommandLineRunner $input 2> ${input}.log
```

Note: This only redirects `stderr` to a file. `stdout` is still printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to redirect stderr to a log file, say '/tmp/myjar.log'

check out [all about bash redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

```
cd /myjarfilepath
LOG="/tmp/myjar.log"
for input in $list
do
 echo "processing $input" > $LOG
 java -Xmx1024m -cp myApp.jar com.CommandLineRunner $input 2>$LOG
done
```

Comment: Java also has a host of logging suites like log4j.  You could also setup a test file to give the input a and step in debug mode inside an IDE.  debugging is a seriously powerful programming tool!

Answer (score 0):

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp myApp.jar com.CommandLineRunner $input 1
```

I did redirected the stdout to a log file. So this leaves the stderr gets printed to the terminal.

The whole process I was running it through jenkins job. Hence the error logs printed in the terminal can be collected as build log file and attached in email.

Comment: examples of the redirection technique would be helpful